# How to use spring Repository without Primary OR composite key?

Tags: spring, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a following table in my company's existing database

```
CREATE TABLE person
 (
    person_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    person_type VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    description TEXT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    created_at DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    updated_at DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
  );
```

**Altering table is not allowed**

How to create a Spring Boot Data JPA entity class with above table without having primary or composite key?

Comment: no that is different